# Why does $(a_n)$ bounded imply that $(b_n)$ is decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why does $(a_n)$ bounded imply that $(b_n)$ is decreasing?

$$(a_n)=a_1,a_2,\dots\tag{1}$$

$$b_n=\sup (a_n,a_{n+1},\dots), c_n=\inf (a_n,a_{n+1},\dots)$$

> If $\left(a_n\right)$ is bounded, then $\left(b_n\right)$ exists and $(b_n)$ is decreasing, $(c_n)$ is increasing.

Why?

Comment: $(a_n)$ bounded implies that each $b_n$ *exists*. That $(b_n)$ is decreasing is obvious (look at the sets you're supping over).

Comment: @DavidMitra Yes, the original words is that obvious--,me silly to see that fact obviously. :(

Comment: @Did Typo, fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $(a_n)$ is bounded insures that each $b_n$ and $c_n$ is defined.

To see that $(b_n)$ is decreasing:

Fix an $n$.

Any upper bound of $\{a_n, a_{n+1}, \cdots\}$ is also an upper bound of  $\{  a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \cdots\}$. In particular, $b_n$ is an upper bound of  $\{  a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \cdots\}$. As $b_{n+1}$ is the least upper bound of  $\{  a_{n+1}, a_{n+2}, \cdots\}$, we have $b_{n+1}\le b_n$.

A similar argument will establish that $(c_n)$ is increasing.

Comment: I understand--! haha:)

Answer (score 2):

- The hypothesis "$(a_n)$ is bounded" is to make sens to the definition of $b_n$ and $c_n$ i.e. they have a finite value.
- We have this general result: if $A\subset B$ then 
  $$\sup(A)\leq \sup (B)\quad \text{and}\quad\inf(A)\geq \inf(B)$$
  so take
  $A_n=\{a_n,a_{n+1},\cdots\}$ and we have $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ and apply the previous result.

Comment: Hi, A=[1,2], sup(A)=2? B=[1,3], sup(A)=3?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: you are welcome, and thanks, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

$$b_n=\sup(a_n,b_{n+1})\implies b_n\geqslant b_{n+1}$$

Comment: sorry, I donot know what's the meaning of $sup(a_n,b_n+1)$

Comment: You do not know what $\sup(x,y)$ is, when $x$ and $y$ are real numbers?

Comment: I know sup(A set) if (x,y) means set {x,y} then I understand, if x,y are arbitrary real numbers, that is complex number system

Comment: "complex number system". What are you talking about? // Yes, $\sup(x,y)$ is $\sup\{x,y\}$.

Comment: Did, do you think you can help me with a little something about sequences? I have put my foot in the mud [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/449834/explicit-formula-for-bernoulli-numbers-by-using-only-the-recurrence-relation/450839#450839) but I haven't obtained any solution really.